# What coding practices do I use in Vaadin to ensure I can record Selenium scripts?

Tags: selenium, tdd, vaadin, selenium-grid

My team is about to start using Vaadin and wants to integrate Selenium tests to allow for Test-driven development.

However I've heard there are issues with recording Selenium scripts out of the box with Vaadin and I'm wondering what practices we need to follow to make sure the scripts can be recorded easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Vaadin use setDebugId(String id) method. All visual components has this method. After that you simply select element by ID.

 WebDriver it look like:

```
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.id("yourElementId"));
el.sendKeys("123");
```

Selenium 1.0

```
 selenium.type("id=yourElementId", "123");
```

But sometime you will need more complex selector. In our project we use XPath with element id. 

 WebDriver it look like:

```
WebElement el = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='yourElementId']/div"));
el.sendKeys("123");
```

Selenium 1.0

```
 selenium.type("//div[@id='yourElementId']/div", "123");
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to get pro user accounts for your team and use the vaadin testbench. You can then profit from the experiences made by senior vaadin developers and save a lot of effort.